# Django Templates First element of a List

Tags: python, django, django-templates, django-filters

I pass a dictionary to my Django Template,

Dictionary & Template is like this -

```
lists[listid] = {'name': l.listname, 'docs': l.userdocs.order_by('-id')}

{% for k, v in lists.items %}
    <ul><li>Count: {{ v.docs.count }}, First: {{ v.docs|first }}</li></ul>
{% endfor %}
```

Now `docs` is a list of `userdocs` type. i.e. is an instance. So `first` filter returns me this instance. From this I need to extract it's `id`. How do I do that?

I tried
`{{ v.docs|first }}.id` and various other futile trials.

Answer (score 63, accepted):

You can use the `{% with %}` templatetag for this sort of thing.

```
{% with v.docs|first as first_doc %}{{ first_doc.id }}{% endwith %}
```

Comment: Hacked around & found an alternate, tell me if this is a bad practice - `{{ v.movies.0.doc.id }}`

Answer (score 77):

You can try this:

```
{{ v.docs.0 }}
```

Like `arr.0`

You can get elements by index (`0`, `1`, `2`, etc.).

Comment: Thank you for a generic answer. I needed first and second ;)

Answer (score 8):

I don't know if this is helpful..

What you want is the first value of an iterable (v.docs) and you are iterating over another encapsulating iterable (lists).

For the count, I would do the same, but for the first element..
I'd iterate over the v.docs individually and retrieve the first value via 
an inner loop.

```
{% for doc in v.docs %}
    {% if v.docs | first %}  
    <li>doc</li>
    {% endif %}
{% endfor %}
```

Note: the first filter is applied to v.docs , not doc.
Yeah. It involves another loop :(

Comment: you must change ```v.docs | first``` to ```v.docs|first``` because you get this error : ```Could not parse the remainder: '|' from '|' ```