# Return the first image from the model using the tag '{{value | first}}'

Tags: python, django, templates

I have a list of photos from which I would like to always be the first to add as a profile photo. I found the following '[|first](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/templates/builtins/#first)' tag in the django documentation, but I have problems to add it in my situation, every time I try to do it in this way, '{{ image_list|first.photo.url }}' i receives nothing.

Any help will be appreciated.

**My models.py**

```
class Image(models.Model):
    photo = models.ImageField()
    added_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    masseurs = models.ForeignKey(Masseurs, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
```

**views.py**

```
masseur = get_object_or_404(Masseurs, pk=masseurs_id)
image_list = Image.objects.filter(masseurs_id = masseurs_id)
return render(request, 'masseur/masseur_detail.html', {'image_list':image_list})
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Django Templates First element of a List](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4286461/django-templates-first-element-of-a-list)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `image_list` is a QuerySet and not a list, `|first` won't work. You can however use:

```
{{ image_list.first.photo.url }}
```

For reference, see : [Accessing Method Calls](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/templates/language/#accessing-method-calls)

> Most method calls attached to objects are also available from within templates. This means that templates have access to much more than just class attributes (like field names) and variables passed in from views.

Comment: is it also possible to use the equivalent of 'slice' in in a situation such as this in the question? if so, what would it look like (for example from documentation example {{ some_list|slice:":2" }})?

Comment: You could slice the queryset in the view, yes.  `{% with image_list|slice:'0' as image %} {{ image.photo.url }} {% endwith %}` I'd wager that route would be much slower than using the model method though.  You can also access by index `{{ image_list.0.photo.url }}`

Comment: so you recommend getting photos from the model view?

Answer (score 1):

Why don't you do it in the view?

```
image = Image.objects.filter(masseurs_id=masseurs_id).first()
```

But if you need to do it in the template:

```
{{ image_list.first.photo.url }}
```

This is because `image_list` is a queryset, so you can get the first item of the queryset with the .first() syntax