# Select first image of image foreign key in django template

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-templates

I want to select first image of an object property set. I created a Property Model with a Foreign Key to an PropertyImages model. How do I access the first image of the property object_set.all in the template. I don;t want to do it in the view function since this should be in the base.html file.

the code:

```
{% for property in properties %}
        
        <div
          style="background-image: url('{{property.propertyimages_set.all|first.url}}'); background-size: 100% 100%; "
          ;
          class="tm-row-featured"
        >
          <div class="featured-content">
            <p><span>Name: </span>{{property.property_name}}</p>
            <hr>
            <p><span>Type: </span>{{property.property_type}}</p>
            <p><span>Price: </span>&#8358;{{property.price}}</p>
            <p><span>Location: </span>{{property.property_state}}</p>
            <p><a href="{% url 'property_details' property.property_slug %}">More info 
            >>></a></p>
          </div>
        </div>
        {% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use **forloop.first** to check if the loop is executed first and then use an appropriate if tag to display the image. Please see the for loop related variables from the link below:

Ref: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.0/ref/templates/builtins/#for

```
{% if forloop.first %}
 # Show first image here

{% endif %}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

[Ref](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29433003/16009366)

```
<div style="background-image: url('{{properties.0.propertyimages_set.url}}'); background-size: 100% 100%;"; class="tm-row-featured">
    <div class="featured-content">
        <p><span>Name: </span>{{properties.0.property_name}}</p>
        <hr>
        <p><span>Type: </span>{{properties.0.property_type}}</p>
        <p><span>Price: </span>&#8358;{{properties.0.price}}</p>
        <p><span>Location: </span>{{properties.0.property_state}}</p>
        <p><a href="{% url 'property_details' properties.0.property_slug %}">More info >>></a></p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

The solutions above didnt work for me. I finally found a way around the solution thus:

```
{% for property in properties %}
        
        
        <div
        
        {% with  property.propertyimages_set.all|first as photo %} style="background-image: url('{{photo.image.url}}'); background-size: 100% 100%; "
          ; {% endwith %}
          class="tm-row-featured"
        >
          <div class="featured-content">
            <p><span>Name: </span>{{property.property_name}}</p>
            <hr>
            <p><span>Type: </span>{{property.property_type}}</p>
            <p><span>Price: </span>&#8358;{{property.price}}</p>
            <p><span>Location: </span>{{property.property_state}}</p>
            <p><a href="{% url 'property_details' property.property_slug %}">More info >>></a></p>
          </div>
        </div>
        {% endfor %}
      </div>
```